# Stencling leaves white pixels on UV overlap

Tags: uv, texture-painting, texture-baking

I am trying to add a design to my trailer and I've decided to try stenciling it. [image]

It's come out pretty well but the ridges have caused some areas to not get colored in. Also, on the ridges themselves some spots are not getting stenciled. I had a similar issue when baking the texture before stenciling, with holes in my diffuse bake on the skinnier parts of the ridges.
[image]

Any help with these issues would be greatly appreciated.

[image]